# Python 2.7: test if characters in a string are all Chinese characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following code tests if characters in a string are all Chinese characters. It works for Python 3 but not for Python 2.7. How do I do it in Python 2.7?

```
for ch in name:
    if ord(ch) < 0x4e00 or ord(ch) > 0x9fff:
        return False
```

Comment: Is `name` a unicode string or a byte string? You don't have to use `ord` here, btw: `if ch < u'\u4e00' or ch > u'\u9fff':` works too.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027450/is-there-a-way-to-know-whether-a-unicode-string-contains-any-chinese-japanese-ch/16028174#16028174

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#  byte str (you probably get from GAE)
In [1]: s = """Chinese (汉语/漢語 Hànyǔ or 中文 Zhōngwén) is a group of related
        language varieties, several of which are not mutually intelligible,"""

#  unicode str
In [2]: us = u"""Chinese (汉语/漢語 Hànyǔ or 中文 Zhōngwén) is a group of related
        language varieties, several of which are not mutually intelligible,"""

#  convert to unicode using str.decode('utf-8')    
In [3]: print ''.join(c for c in s.decode('utf-8') 
                   if u'\u4e00' <= c <= u'\u9fff')
汉语漢語中文

In [4]: print ''.join(c for c in us if u'\u4e00' <= c <= u'\u9fff')
汉语漢語中文
```

To make sure all the characters are Chinese, something like this should do:

```
all(u'\u4e00' <= c <= u'\u9fff' for c in name.decode('utf-8'))
```

In your python application, use unicode internally - decode early  & encode late - creating a [unicode sandwich](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

Comment: Only one comment - rather than decoding into a nonce value, it might be better to store the decoded unicode object, and work internally with unicode.

Comment: @Marcin -- You are absolutely right, will add a note, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This works fine for me in Python 2.7, *provided `name` is a `unicode()` value*:

```
>>> ord(u'\u4e00') < 0x4e00
False
>>> ord(u'\u4dff') < 0x4e00
True
```

You do not have to use `ord` here if you compare the character directly with unicode values:

```
>>> u'\u4e00' < u'\u4e00'
False
>>> u'\u4dff' < u'\u4e00'
True
```

Data from an incoming request will not yet have been decoded to unicode, you'll need to do that first. Explicitly set the `accept-charset` attribute on your form tag to ensure that the browser uses the correct encoding:

```py
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="...">
```

then decode the data on the server side:

```
name = self.request.get('name').decode('utf8')
```

Comment: I am working on Google App Engine with Python. The `name` is obtained by `name = self.request.get('name')` from a form, and the user need to enter Chinese characters only. Do I need to convert `name` into unicode? And how?

Comment: @Tang: Yes, you'd have to convert the data to Unicode first. Browsers usually use the encoding of the HTML page, so if you serve your pages with `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8` then you can assume you can decode as UTF-8 as well.