# How to identify and remove garbage characters?

Tags: python, utf-8, text-processing, pdftotext, mojibake

I have a Chinese text file that has lot of garbled text in between the good Chinese text (from a PDF to TXT conversion.)

How would I go about removing the garbled text while keeping the Chinese/English text intact?

[Here is the shortened version of the file](https://gist.github.com/echan00/acde1d7e460cd9e467dfd612ea14ab66)

Comment: See if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441633/python-2-7-test-if-characters-in-a-string-are-all-chinese-characters?lq=1

Comment: @ditkin I still want to keep any English text and all related English and Chinese punctuation, it seems like that answer strips everything but the Chinese.